# Place one image in a larger field with Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to use Image Magick to do this: take one image, shrink it a bit, and place it in a larger white field (of size 1280x720). For example, with Image1 as the source, the end result should resemble this:

[image]

The script I wrote so far is this (DOS command):

`magick convert -size 1280x720 xc:white -page 512x384+40+40 img1.png -layers flatten out.png`

But: That's not shrinking the source image; it remains the same size, mostly filling up my field. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> identify 1.png

```
1.png PNG 1014x400 1014x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 255c 108449B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

---

```
  convert -size 1280x720 xc:black \
          \( 1.png \) -geometry  512x384+40+40   -composite \
          a.png
```

> identify a.png

```
a.png PNG 1280x720 1280x720+0+0 16-bit sRGB 319036B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

===========================================================

```
  convert -size 1280x720 xc:black \
          \( 1.png \) -geometry  +40+40   -composite \
          b.png
```

> identify b.png

```
b.png PNG 1280x720 1280x720+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 124969B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

===========================================================

```
  convert -size 1280x720 xc:black \
          \( 1.png -resize 500x500 \) -geometry  +40+40   -composite \
          c.png
```

> identify c.png

```
c.png PNG 1280x720 1280x720+0+0 16-bit sRGB 307045B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

=================================================================

```
  convert -size 1280x720 xc:black \
          \( 1.png -resize 50x50 \) -geometry  +40+40   -composite \
          d.png
```

> identify d.png

```
d.png PNG 1280x720 1280x720+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11438B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

================================================================

Comment: Awesome, thank you!